# R: substitute pattern in formula for a variable name

Tags: r

I have a general function that calls an expression that uses a formula and I would like to pass this functions to various environments that store some specific variables and modify parts of a formula designated by a specific pattern.

Here is an example:

```
# Let's assume I have an environment storing a variable
env <- new.env()
env$..M.. <- "Sepal.Length"

# And a function that calls an expression
func <- function() summary(lm(..M.. ~ Species, data = iris))$r.squared

# And let's assume I am trying to evaluate it within the environment
environment(func) <- env

# And I would like to have some method that makes it evaluate as:
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris))$r.squared
```

So far I came up with a very dirty solution based on deparsing the function down to string, greping and then parsing it back. It goes like this:

```
tfunc <- paste(deparse(func), collapse = "")
tfunc <- gsub("\\.\\.M\\.\\.", ..M.., tfunc, perl = TRUE)
tfunc <- eval(parse(text = tfunc))
```

So yes, it works, but I would like to find a cleaner method, that would somewhat magically substitute this `..M..` pattern into `Sepal.Length` without a need for all this parsing and deparsing.

So I would really appreciate some help and hints for that problem.

Comment: how in the world did you end up here

Comment: I am experimenting a little bit ...

Comment: one thought comes to mind is inserting a line into the function itself to make this work: `func <- function() summary(lm(..M.. ~ Species, data = iris))$r.squared; expr <- quote(iris$..M.. <- iris$Sepal.Length); body(func) <- as.call(c(list(as.name('{')), list(expr, body(func)))); func()`

Comment: Hmm, but this does modify `iris` which is stored in the global environment, right? I would like to avoid modifying global environment as this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: so then remove the iris$ part, this modifies the objects created within the function, if `iris` and `..M..` were not created in the function, then it will look in the global sure `quote(..M.. <- iris$Sepal.Length)`